# SSRS Report Skip Page

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS Report that I need help with  -

So the design looks like below - 
[image]

You will notice that there are page breaks between each table. So each "account" starts on a new page.

What currently happens is if there are no results in the table I get the table returned with the following

[image]

So an extra page is created with a table telling us there are no results.....however is there any way that the table and therefore the page is just skipped/ignored altogether if no results exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `Hidden` property in the `Visibility` section of the table properties to `true` when there are no records in the dataset that populates that table and it shouldn't render in your final report:

```
=iif(CountRows() = 0, true, false)
```

---

Page break options on the table properties:

[image]

Comment: So I've done as you say and all that does is hide the table - it still creates the blank page as there is another table after that on the statement...

Comment: @ikilledbill  Are you putting manual page breaks in or are you specifying a page break after the table?

Comment: The way the report is designed is that there are 7 tables which are equal to 7 accounts a customer could have. Between each table is a Rectangle, which I tell to Page Break on....as this is the only way I know how to get each table on a new page. If though for one of the accounts there were no results in the table ultimately I would like to table to not appear and the page not display - could you put the table in the rectangle?

Comment: @ikilledbill  I mean, if you have specified in the table properties to put a page break after the table when the table is not visible, the page break is not put into the report.  If you have separate elements that generate the page breaks you will need to hide those as well.  Personally, I would get rid of the parts that are created just to put page breaks in, and set the property on the tables.  I have edited my post to show you what I mean.

Comment: That seems to be what I'm after - Thanks. However when I click "Add a Page break after" and add the following =iif(CountRows() = 0, true, false) to the Tablix Properties under "Show or hide based on an expression" It still hides the table even though there are results?

Comment: @ikilledbill  I think that will depend on the scope of your table.  Does it hide every table or just some?  Either way, you just need to find a way to see if that table has rows displaying either by counting in the manner I suggested (Which works in my dummy report) or by replicating the table filtering in your `iif` statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130018/discussion-between-iamdave-and-ikilledbill).